# Issue with regular expression output

Tags: python, regex, syntax, python-re

I am using the following code to filter out phone numbers from a text file.

```
import re

pattern = (r'\d*-\d*-\d*')
names = (r'\w*')

with open('records.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        matches = re.findall(pattern, line)
        namesMatch = re.findall(names, line) 
        if matches:
            print(matches)
        elif namesMatch:
            print(namesMatch + ":")`
```

I am getting the following output:

```
['John']
['222-333-4447']
['423-444-5678']
['123-455-1223']
['Paul']
['423-444-5778']
```

I want a similar output but in string format like below:

```
John:
222-333-4447
423-444-5678
123-455-1223
Paul:
423-444-5778
```

Comment: I am getting the following output:
    ['123-455-1223']
    ['222-333-4447']
    ['423-444-5678']
    ['123-455-1223']
    ['221-353-4747']
    ['423-444-5778']


I want a similar output but in string format like below:
    123-455-1223
    222-333-4447
    423-444-5678
   123-455-1223
   221-353-4747
   423-444-5778

Comment: it sounds like you have more details to add to this question ... please add the additional comments to the question as code, include both a given input and the expected output for that input

Comment: @JoranBeasley

I have edited the code.

I am getting the following output:
    ['John']`enter code here`
    ['222-333-4447']
    ['423-444-5678']
    ['123-455-1223']
    ['Paul']
    ['423-444-5778']


I want a similar output but in string format like below:
    John:
    222-333-4447
    423-444-5678
    123-455-1223
    Paul:
    423-444-5778

Comment: please provide a snippet of sample input and then we can probably help ... and make sure our example input actually looks like your input because the answer you get will look like that @Nithin

Comment: Maybe `re.findall(r'(\w+):((?:\s*\d+-\d+-\d+)+)', f.read())`? Or, something like https://regex101.com/r/7FaFEk/1?

Comment: @JoranBeasley

Input text file contains:
.........................................................
John.................
.............222-333-4447.......
.. 423-444-5678 ....
.................123-455-1223...............
........Paul...
......423-444-5778.......................................

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/YoMdJs, is it correct?

Comment: please edit original question

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that seems right from his comment i would post that answer

Comment: maybe you should simply use `matches[0]` instead of `matches`

Comment: @JoranBeasley I hope this will really be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re
text = """John................. .............222-333-4447....... .. 423-444-5678 .... .................123-455-1223............... ........Paul... ......423-444-5778....................................... – 
Nithin"""
pattern=r"(\w+)((?:[\s:.]*\d+[-—–]\d+[-—–]\d+)+)"
print( [(x, " ".join(y.replace('.','').split())) for x,y in re.findall(pattern, text)] )
```

Output:

```
[('John', '222-333-4447 423-444-5678 123-455-1223'), ('Paul', '423-444-5778')]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YoMdJs).

*Details*:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `((?:[\s:.]*\d+[-—–]\d+[-—–]\d+)+)` - Group 1: one or more occurrences of the following pattern sequence

  - `[\s:.]*` - zero or more whitespaces, colons and dots
  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `[-—–]` - a hyphen or dash
  - `\d+[-—–]\d+` - one or more digits, a dash, one or more digits.